# forking from google code to github with synchronization

Tags: git

There is a repository on GoogleCode
https://code.google.com/p/iosched/

I would like to fork it  and work with this repository in github environment,
at the same time, I would like to be able to pull from the original repository at google code if any changes are present there.

What are the steps to accomplish this task?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `fork` it, make a `branch`. Push branch to github. Then when you want to `pull` changes, change back to master fork, `pull`, then do a `merge` with your github `branch`.

Comment: Forgot to mention you may need to change your remote when you branch and when you change back to master... you can view with git remote -v